# Is there any way I can speed up this program? Python

Tags: python, image

The purpose of this program is to modify pixels in an image. Currently, I am generating three random numbers, between -150 and 150, and iterating through each pixel in the image, and adding the random number to each of the three bands for each pixel. It is not too time consuming to make one image, about 5 seconds, but I want to make 100 or more, and I was hoping there is some way to speed up this program.

```
import time
from PIL import Image
import random
startTime = time.time()
tempTime = startTime
def modifyImage(curImage):
    pixels = curImage.load() #Makes an array of all the pixels
    offsets = [random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150)] #Puts three random numbers in a list
    tempList = []
    for y in range(img1.getbbox()[3]): #the parameter passed to the range gets the lower bounding box of the image, i.e. the height
        for x in range(img1.getbbox()[2]): #The parameter passed to the range gets the left bounding box of the image, i.e. the width
            tempList = []
            #It would be much easier to directly modify the values of the pixels, but Pillow stores pixels as tuples and are therefore immutable. So I made a list which will store
            #the result of the sum of the current value of the band of each pixel and the random number generated, and then change the entire tuple later.
            for i in range(3): 
                if pixels[x, y][i] + offsets[i] > 256: #In case the current pixel value + the random number is greater than 256, to avoid errors
                    tempList.append(256)
                elif pixels[x, y][i] + offsets[i] < 0: #In case the current pixel value  + the random number is less than 0, to avoid errors
                    tempList.append(0)
                else:
                    tempList.append(pixels[x, y][i] + offsets[i])
            pixels[x, y] = (tempList[0], tempList[1], tempList[2]) #Changes the entire tuple since I can't change individual values within
    return curImage

direct = "C:\\Users\Stamm\Downloads\FYF Project\Output\output"
for i in range(1, 101): #Runs the function 100 times and saves the output
    img1 = Image.open("C:\\Users\Stamm\Downloads\FYF Project\Screenshot01.jpg")
    img = modifyImage(img1)
    img.save(direct + str(i) + ".jpg")
    tempTime = time.time()
    print("Image " + str(i) + " Done: " + str(tempTime - startTime) + " seconds")
    startTime = tempTime
```

Comment: Have a look at `numpy` and how it can be used to manipulate images.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Christian's comment, you want to use NumPy which will allow you to avoid nested loops which as super slow.

```
pixels = np.array(img1)
offsets = np.random.randint(-150, 150, 3)  # Create 3 random offsets
new_pixels = pixels + offsets  # Add offsets to pixels
capped_pixels = np.clip(new_pixels, 0, 256)  # Limit pixel values to between 0 and 256
```

If this is still too slow you can look into the `numba` package which extends NumPy. It also allows for Cuda acceleration if you have an Nvidia GPU.

Comment: So the NumPy and Pillow libraries are compatible like that? NumPy will read the Image object and automatically convert it to an array? No need for img1.load()? So adding the array of 3 random numbers will add them to each tuple in the 2D array of pixels respectively? If so, that's pretty awesome. Thank you both for your help. I didn't know about that clip method either, I was using np.where().

Comment: `from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open("C:\\Users\Stamm\Downloads\FYF Project\Madi.jpg")
pixels = np.array(img)
offsets = np.random.randint(-150, 150, 3)
new_pixels = pixels + offsets
resultingPixels = np.clip(new_pixels, 0, 256)
resultImage = Image.fromarray(resultingPixels)
resultImage.show() `  This threw an error, I'm assuming it has to do with adding the 2D array of tuples, pixels, to offsets. It bugs me that there's a limit on comment length. I want to post the error for you but it is too long even if I make it its own comment.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I did some debugging and the addition is fine, the clipping is fine, for some reason "np.fromarray(resultingPixels)" is throwing the error. I did discover that turning a pillow Image object into a NumPy array turns the tuples representing each pixel into arrays. So maybe it is something to do with that the "fromarray()" method is expecting there to be tuples in the 2D array instead of arrays.

Comment: From what I can see from other posts, casting the array to ```uint8``` might help. ie ```capped_pixels = capped_pixels.astype("uint8")```.

Comment: But I don't think it being a 3-d array is the issue. That would be expected for a color image.

Comment: Oh yes I figured it out, I thought I left a comment saying that but I guess not. I condensed the code down quite a bit. I also made it so the three random numbers being added to each pixel have to be more than 20 from 0 and have to be more than 20 apart from each other random number, just to make the filter more interesting. Here's my code. And I'm new here, is there a better way to format code in comments?

Comment: `sampleArr = np.arange(-150, -19, 1) + np.arange(20, 151, 1)
  randArr = np.random.choice(sampleArr, 3) #Makes an array of 3 random numbers between -150 and -20 or 20 and 150
    while np.any(abs(np.roll(randArr, 2) - randArr) < 20): #Continually makes a new array of random numbers if any of the numbers have a distance of lower than 20 between them
        randArr = np.random.choice(sampleArr, 3)
    return Image.fromarray(np.clip(np.array(curImage) + randArr, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)) #Adds random array to each pixel, makes each value between 0-255, turns array back into image `